# How do I extract dates from an Excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to extract dates from an Excel sheet using the pandas library.

```
data = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['birthday'])
```

This works but I don't really know how to work with DataFrames and I just need a list/array of the ages, so I tried to convert it into a numpy array:

```
array = df.to_numpy()
```

This works fine as well but elements of the array look like:

```
[datetime.datetime(1983, 6, 4, 0, 0)]
```

But I can't use the methods provided by datetime to convert the dates.

What would be the best approach to get a list/array of ages eventually?

## Update:

```
               Birthday
1   2002-03-15 00:00:00
2   1999-04-17 00:00:00
3   1993-06-04 00:00:00
4   1997-07-04 00:00:00
5   1983-08-09 00:00:00
6   2000-01-10 00:00:00
7   1996-08-20 00:00:00
8   2003-11-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: You have a list of datetime objects. I'd try looping through them and interacting with the datetime objects therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your dates column is called `birthday` then something like the following :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Birthday' : pd.date_range(start='01/01/88',end='02/02/95',freq='M')})
df['Today'] = pd.datetime(2019,6,13) # probably better to use the datetime module.
df['Years'] = (df['Today'] - df['Birthday']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
    print(df.head(5))
    Birthday    Today   Years
0   1988-01-31  2019-06-13  31.365463
1   1988-02-29  2019-06-13  31.286063
2   1988-03-31  2019-06-13  31.201188
3   1988-04-30  2019-06-13  31.119051
4   1988-05-31  2019-06-13  31.034176
```

Then simply cast the col to a np.array

```
 a = np.array(df['Years'])
    print(a)
    array([31.36546267, 31.28606337, 31.20118825, 31.11905104, 31.03417592,
       30.95203871, 30.8671636 , 30.78228848, 30.70015127, 30.61527615,
       30.53313894, 30.44826382, 30.36338871, 30.28672731, 30.20185219,
       30.11971498, 30.03483987, 29.95270266, 29.86782754, 29.78295242]
```

Comment: Thanks alot but I get an error for unmatching types while performing the subtraction, python states that they are str and DatetimeIndex

Comment: @Sterial I guess birthday isn't a date column, try `df['Birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birthday'])`

Comment: I tried and ended up with this error:                                           ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Comment: Are you able to post some sample data? Just ten rows or so

Comment: @Sterial apologies for the delay, in the midst of a forecast! I've just tested my code on your sample and it worked, the only thing I can think of is that there are some none datetime values in your df. use `df['Birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birthday'],errors='coerce)` to coerce those pesky outliers. You should investigate those rows to see what's happening though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there was a row with irregular data in it, which messed up the conversion.
Handling of the types works fine now, thanks!

Comment: No problem, make sure you green tick the answer and don't leave comments as answers :) you should delete this one